# Pandas DataFrame check colums value in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have test_df with columns 'MonthAbbr' and 'PromoInterval'

Example output

```
1017174           Jun  Mar,Jun,Sept,Dec
1017175           Mar  Mar,Jun,Sept,Dec
1017176           Feb  Mar,Jun,Sept,Dec
1017177           Feb  Feb,May,Aug,Nov
1017178           Jan  Feb,May,Aug,Nov
1017179           Jan  Mar,Jun,Sept,Dec
1017180           Jan  Mar,Jun,Sept,Dec
```

I want add column-indicator is month in promo interval, which will =1 if MonthAbbr in PromoInterval for current row, =0 otherwise

Is there more efficient way?

```
for ind in test_df.index:
  test_df.set_value(ind ,'IsPromoInThisMonth',
  test_df.MonthAbbr.astype(str)[ind] in (test_df.PromoInterval.astype(str)[ind])
```

Comment: Kaggle- Rossman, if i'm not mistaken ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit faster:

```
%%timeit
test_df['IsPromoInThisMonth'] = [x in y for x, y in zip(test_df['MonthAbbr'], 
                                                        test_df['PromoInterval'])]

1000 loops, best of 3: 317 µs per loop
```

Than your approach:

```
%%timeit
for ind in test_df.index:
    test_df.set_value(ind ,'IsPromoInThisMonth',
    test_df.MonthAbbr.astype(str)[ind] in (test_df.PromoInterval.astype(str)[ind]))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop
```

**UPDATE**

Using a function with `apply` is slower than the list comprehension:

```
%%timeit
test_df['IsPromoInThisMonth'] = test_df.apply(lambda x: x[0] in x[1], axis=1)

1000 loops, best of 3: 804 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! Really much faster. But maybe it's possible to make it trough pandas apply/map function?

Comment: You can use `apply` (see updated answer above). But it is slower due to the function calling overhead.